# Running BERT embeddings on a large dataset?

Tags: python, bert-language-model

I am trying to figure out a way to run BERT embeddings on a large dataset (several hundred novels) in order to then plot similar words to a set of keywords. I have done the same analysis in word2vec so the idea is to see if BERT embeddings would be different.

I know understand that BERT embeddings has a small token limit (512). I found some code for splitting a text into smaller chunks but am running into some problems. Below is my code. It probably has more problems than I am even discovering yet, and I'm not yet sure how to proceed from here. Any tips would be appreciated!

`

```
pip3 install torch --index-url https://download.pytorch.org/whl/cpu

from transformers import pipeline
unmasker = pipeline('fill-mask', model='bert-base-uncased')
unmasker("Hello I'm a [MASK] model.")

from transformers import BertTokenizer, BertModel
tokenizer = BertTokenizer.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased')
model = BertModel.from_pretrained("bert-base-uncased"))
output = model(**encoded_input)

#trying this out with smaller but still long dataset--three files truncated together
import os
base_dir = "/Users/Dez Miller/OneDrive/Desktop/test_corpus/"
all_docs = []
docs = os.listdir(base_dir)

#reading through and checking
for doc in docs:
    if not doc.startswith(' . '):
        with open(base_dir + doc, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
            text=file.read()
            all_docs.append(text)

len(all_docs)

    #got this function from here for splitting texts
def get_split(all_docs):
    l_total = []
    l_partial = []
    if len(all_docs.split())//150>0:
        n = len(all_docs.split())//150
    else:
        n = 1
    for w in range(n):
        if w == 0:
            l_partial = all_docs.split()[:200]
            l_total.append(" ".join(l_partial))
        else:
            l_partial = all_docs.split()[w*150:w*150 + 200]
            l_total.append(" ".join(l_partial))
        return l_total
get_split(all_docs)

-------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError        Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[18], line 1
----> 1 get_split(all_docs)

Cell In[17], line 5, in get_split(all_docs)
      3 l_total = []
      4 l_partial = []
----> 5 if len(all_docs.split())//150>0:
      6     n = len(all_docs.split())//150
      7 else:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You define `all_docs=[]` as a list, which contains the strings you want to split.

the get_split function is missing.If you have function that splits a single text file you can do it like this:

```
for doc in docs:
    if not doc.startswith(' . '):
        with open(base_dir + doc, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
            splited_text = split_text(file.read()) # <- split here and return a list
            all_texts.extend(splited_text) # <- include the spited strings into the list
```

---

Be aware that you storing all this in memory